# Buy products from website inside iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, e-commerce

We need to be able to buy products from an external e-commerce store from inside a mobile app.

The app tracks how much water you drink each day and our client wants the ability to buy bottles of water directly inside the app and have this link to his e-commerce store to manage orders and inventory.

Ideally he wants a "one click" buy it now option - how would this be possible?

Easiest way would be to embed a web view of the store in the app but there must be a cleaner, sexier way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the third party payment gateways like stripe, brain tree etc. Save the card information for one payment click.

NOTE: These services will take their cut.